# Get List from a Child Model

Tags: c#

I created my list from model `FolderModel` to `Add` something like this:

```
var folders = new List<FolderModel>();
using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand())
            {
                ...
                        try
                        {
                            folders.Add(
                                new FolderModel()

                                {
                                    Id = (int)reader["id"],
                                    Name = (string)reader["foldername"]
                                }
                            );
                        }
 ...
```

So I have my List in the folders variable and can add it with `folders.Add` and the `new FolderModel()`.

Now I have the problem, that a Parent model is over the folder model and i need to use it. And my problem is, I cannot get the FolderModel List again.

Parentmodel:

```
public class ParentModel
    {
        public FolderModel FolderModel { get; set; }
    }
```

Foldermodel:

```
public class FolderModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

How can I achieve the List when I start from the ParentModel?

```
ParentModel pm = new ParentModel();
var folders = List<pm.FolderModel>();
```

Does not work for example. How can I achieve my `Parentmodel.FolderModel` list and what do I have to write instead of the `new FolderModel()` line?

Comment: Please share the `FolderModel` class

Comment: What's the relationship between the `Folder` and `FolderModel` class?

Comment: @GiladGreen I shared it.
@ juharr sorry, it was wrong Folder should be FolderModel, my mistake. It is/was the same. I just have a parentmodel over my foldermodel and simply don't know how to access it via a List.

Answer (score 0):

Update the ParentModel

```
public class ParentModel {
    public List<FolderModel> FolderModels { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can assign the list to the parent

```
var folders = new List<FolderModel>();
//...execute command and populate folders
ParentModel pm = new ParentModel();
pm.FolderModels = folders;
```

Comment: For the first, this works, but I cannot iterate over it in the View, because I need in the View I need the `List<Models.ParentModel>`, to achieve the values of the FolderModel and of an other Model.